# assert as a friend class

Tags: c++, assert, friend

I can not declare neither assert class, nor assert function as a friendly to my class.

Am I right with such a declaration?

```
class Baka
{
private:
friend assert;          //invalid friend declaration
friend void assert();   //expected an identifer
public:
}
```

I've already googled a lot, but I can't find right arguments for assert() and the real name of the "assert" class(
I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Please provide declaration of `assert` with your code.

Comment: I assume you mean [`assert` from the `<cassert>` header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert)? Then no you can't declare it as a friend because it's not a function it's *preprocessor macro*.

Comment: There is no `assert` class, and the `assert` macro doesn't need to be a friend. Why do you think you need to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assert` isn't a function, it's a macro. Therefore if you have `<cassert>` included upstream it will be expanded by the pre-processor before compilation

```
// cassert file
// Not debug version
#define assert(_Expression)     ((void)0)
```

So your class actually says

```
class Baka
{
private:
  friend ((void)0);          //invalid friend declaration
  friend void ((void)0)();   //expected an identifer
public:
}
```

Which obviously shouldn't compile.

Comment: And it's certainly not a class.